# Cast decimal as int when a specific value is found

Tags: sql

I have a query that compares data between weeks using CTEs.  One of things it stores is percentage data.  I am trying to convert or cast any value that is equal to 100.00.

For example, here is what the result would look like

```
Name     Percentage     Other
App1     99.56          5.5
App2     100.00         6
```

I am hoping to remove the zero's from the 100.  I have tried some case statements but I never get the results I am looking for.  Here is what I have now.

```
SELECT
    f.Application,
    f.Percentage,
    f.Other,
    CASE
        WHEN f.Percentage = 100.00
        THEN 100
    END AS Percentage
FROM Table1 f
```

Currently, the values that are 100.00 are changed to 100.  However, everything not equal to 100.00 is nulled out.  I can get rid of the NULLs by adding

```
ELSE f.Percentage
```

But then 100.00 is not changed.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: A SQL field/column cannot contain multiple data types, meaning you can't have one record with a `float/decimal` value and another as an `int`. As far as I know (though there are many people on this site far more knolwedgeable than I am in SQL), a string-type (`nvarchar` for example) would be able to handle both decimal and integer values, though your data would then, of course, be returned as a string-value.

Comment: What is consuming this query? Why does the extra `.00` matter? This sounds like something you could (should) handle in the display code.

Comment: You are confusing CAST-ing datatypes with Formatting output strings.  You need the later.  A column must always have the same datatype, it cannot have one datatype for one row and a different datatype in the next row.

Comment: You could cast it as text and replace `.00` by `''`, or you could use a conditional format in your report.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, you can't have a single SQL column that contains multiple data types.

That being said, whether or not it's useful in your case remains to be seen, but a string-type like `nvarchar` can handle both, though your code would need to be able to handle them as strings instead of numbers.

An example would be something like this:

```
SELECT
    f.Application,
    f.Percentage,
    f.Other,
    CASE
        WHEN f.Percentage = 100.00
        THEN '100'
        ELSE CAST(f.Percentage as nvarchar(10))
    END AS Percentage
FROM Table1 f
```

The `Percentage` column would now be of type `nvarchar`, but it would return values in this fashion:

```
Name     Percentage     Other
App1     99.56          5.5
App2     100            6
App3     91.23          3.5
App4     94.41          4.8
App5     100            6
```

Comment: Since I create 2 CTEs and then combine at the end, would I just need to add these changes to the end or to each CTE?  Also, this is all done in SQL Reporting Services so the data coming in is fine.

Comment: If the CTE results are combined into a single resultset as decimals, you can have this query wrapping them when you return your final resultset, instead of doing it for each CTE.

Comment: Actually one last thing that I just remembered.  In my report, I sum and average the values.  I think this will break if they are varchars.

Comment: Correct. You'd have to cast them as `float` or `decimal` before doing the calculation: `SUM(CAST(Percentage As Float))`.

Comment: Sorry had to find the correct function.  Looks like this will work =Sum(CDec(Fields!.FiledName.Value))

Comment: @maltman Why would you convert to strings in the query only to convert them _back_ to numbers to sum in the report.  Just keep everything as numbers and format the numbers in the report to remove any trailing zeros!

Comment: @D Stanley I have tried that a few times but when I do a convert to int, the decimal remains.  I would prefer that but I haven't been able to get that to work.

Comment: Just tested with float and it looks like it works.  No more converting a second time.